# Strange behavior of exception section during unit test in Python 3.7

Tags: python, unit-testing, xunit, python-3.7

I have some sqlite DB creation code. There are several options - if the file existed or not, or if it gets an error (writing to the HDD, wrong DB name, format, etc.). If the method works right, it returns True, if it throws an exception, it will return False:

```
def create_db():
    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
        with db:
            db.execute("SELECT name FROM db_name WHERE type='table'")
        if os.path.isfile(db_name):
            my_logger.info('The DB already existed!')
            return 'DB existed'
        else:
            db = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
            with db:
                db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS City_Weather (fields_description_here)''')
                my_logger.info('The DB was created successfully!')
            return 'DB created'

    except Exception as e:
        my_logger.info(e)
        return False
```

And I wrote this unit test for the function:

```
class ReadersTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_create_db(self):
    self.assertEqual(create_db(), 'DB existed')
```

The strange behaviour begins where I try to init my tests:

```
DB existed != False

Expected :False
Actual   :DB existed
<Click to see difference>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.2\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\diff_tools.py", line 32, in _patched_equals
old(self, first, second, msg)
 File     
"C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 839, in assertEqual
assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
 File "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", 
line 832, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: False != 'DB existed'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", 
line 59, in testPartExecutor
  yield
  File "C:\Users\path\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in run
testMethod()
File "C:\file_path_to_project\utest.py", line 12, in test_create_db
  self.assertEqual(readers.Readers.create_db(), 'DB existed')
```

Why is the unit test module waiting for "False" statement as the correct? During testing, my DB is created and it should pass this test but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, `create_db` returns a string or `False`; it never returns `True`.

Comment: Your traceback, which claims that the expected return value is `False`, doesn't correspond to the actual test, which expects `DB existed`.

Comment: Well you return `False` in the exception. The stacktrace is trying to tell you that `False != "DB existed"` so something is triggering an exception.

Comment: I've split "True" to two statements - "DB existed" and "DB created".

Comment: I thought that connecting to a DB that doesn't exist creates it, so the check after connecting to it would be redundant.

Comment: On a design note, don't catch an exception just to return `False`. If there's an error, and you don't know how to handle it, just re-raise it. It's good practice to have a function always return values of the same type (with the exception being that `None` can be thought of as a valid value of every type).

Comment: Adding to chepner's comment above, if you do not follow the single type for returns, at least always document the types of returns and when each of them will happen.

Answer (score 1):

This assert is failing

```
self.assertEqual(create_db(), 'DB existed')
```

actually you are waiting for `'DB existed'` but the function is returning `False`, so you must be having an exception that causes it to return `False`

Comment: If you'll try to run this code - you will see that file will be created and there will be no exception.

Comment: That's impossible. Something has to trigger the exception and the `False` return.

Comment: I don't know what happens when you run it in the test, but I see exceptions are being captured and that causes False to be returned.

You are capturing the exception in the last 3 lines of the create_db function.

Comment: Just copy those 17 strings and try)) but please add to the beginning: import sqlite

Comment: Sorry I cannot try it, but I don't see any declaration of `db_name`. Probably that is causing the exception. You may need to pass it as parameter to `create_db`